# How do I keep the xrandr settings after reboot?

Tags: xrandr, display-resolution

So I repaired my screen resolution using xrandr, but it disappears after reboot. I don't know how to fix this thing and I couldn't find any recent tutorials that suit me, because I am missing all the .conf or .profile files needed.

Comment: Look at Richard's answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128463/how-to-control-brightness I had the same problem and it worked fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a script at startup that uses xrandr to set display options](http://askubuntu.com/questions/609490/running-a-script-at-startup-that-uses-xrandr-to-set-display-options)

Comment: Thing is I can't find that xorg.conf thing and it makes me mad.

Comment: Well, I don't see how that might help my resolution problem. I just want to run some commands at startup, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The latest 15.04 has no file named xorg.conf , so you have to create it.
It should be in /etc/X11 ,mine looks like this ,the system will boot with the desired settings.(you will have to adjust the file for it to work properly for you).

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI2"
    Modeline "2560x1080" 230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "2560x1080"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "HDMI2"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "2560x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```