# Ubuntu 16.04 do not detect monitor samsung 19"

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

I have an Intel G33/G31 Express Chip in my Foxconn desktop computer.
The Ubuntu does not detect my analogic monitor Samsung SB19B300B.

This monitor has 1366 x 768 max resolution.

In the System setting Display, Ubuntu only shows me the options 1024 x 768 (4:3) and 800 x 600 (4:3) for resolution and shows me "Unknown display" but DOES NOT show me 16:9 relations for 1366 x 768 resolution (60 Hz).

When I run the recommendations of "How to set a custom resolution?" I obtain this results:

```
root@tomas-OEM:/home/tomas# cvt 1366 768 60
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

root@tomas-OEM:/home/tomas#  xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

root@tomas-OEM:/home/tomas# xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1368x768_60.00
xrandr: cannot find output "VGA-0"

root@tomas-OEM:/home/tomas# xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"
VGA1

root@tomas-OEM:/home/tomas# xrandr -s 1368x768
Size 1368x768 not found in available modes
```

Use as a temporary solution while finding a better way:

I create a script with the commands:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00" 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -hsync + vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr -s 1368x768
```

I set it as executable and I add it to the "applications at startup" 
But I do not think it's good because the start takes more time and works like OS windows performance!

Comment: do not hink so Mr. Elder, the problem is not how to custom  resolution, the problem is how Ubuntu show me the correct (16:9)  resolution to set?

Comment: My apologies for your confusion. Your answer is indeed there just plug the appropriate values for your monitor into the **cvt** line. IN your case `cvt 1366 768 60` proceed with the xrandr steps using the modeline from the cvt output as a guide.

Comment: OK, my apologise, I was wrong with VGA-0 instead of VGA1,I said I am not expert Ubuntu comands

Comment: But when I reboot, the system return to the (4:3) resolution and forgot all changes made .   What I need to do additionally?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/609490/running-a-script-at-startup-that-uses-xrandr-to-set-display-options

Comment: Please [edit] new information into your post rather than placing it in a  comment. Comments can get deleted for a number of reasons and are a great place to ask for information but a poor place to provide it. In this case I've edited it into your post for you, but in future please do so. Thank you!